# Input field woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to have order notes on the cart page instead of on the checkout page.

I actually only need to have an input field on the cart page and have the inputted text passed on to the order in admin. Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: What did you tyr so far?

Comment: Hi,
I found a code that inserts a custom field in checkout and I tried to modify this so it would work in cart but it wasn't successful. Someone later told me that it would be impossible to modify it for the cart page so now I am back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

You can override your templates:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/